# 3G-modem for Linux supporting USB 3.0

Tags: networking, 3g

I've laptop with three USB3.0-ports.OS is Linux Mint 13 (yeah, it's Ubuntu-based). My modem **Huawei E1552/E1800** could work in two modes:

1) as flash with drivers

2) modem

The device is operating as modem and seen in *Network Manager* if only it's attached before OS loading. If after, it's detected as flash. The all mine attempts and games with *usb_modeswitch* are in vain and wasn't came to good.

So I would like to ask if there are such modems' model (it's not important what the manufucturer is):

1) that has single operating mode (modem)

or

2) if it supports 2 modes, I'll be able to swich device into the mode without much hassle.

Comment: If you need 3G, I'd suggest you start looking at the offers your local mobile provider(s) have. They usually have reduced prices if you get a data plan and so on. If you already have a SIM card, go to the mobile provider you purchased it from, as this will ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make device detectable as modem by force switching it into "only modem" mode:

- find the appropriate modem TTY

> ls /dev/ttyUSB* (usually ttyUSB0)

connect [minicom](http://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom) to modem

> minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0

send command

> AT^U2DIAG=0 (only modem mode)

unplug and plug modem again,

you can see your mobile wireless connection in Network Manager

Other AT-commands:

1. AT^U2DIAG=1 (modem + CD-ROM)
2. AT^U2DIAG=6 (only network card mode)
3. AT^U2DIAG=268 для E1750 (network card + CD-ROM + Card Reader)
4. AT^U2DIAG=276 для E1750 (network card + CD-ROM + Card Reader)
5. AT^U2DIAG=256 (modem + Card Reader)